# Powershell -- Exporting to CSV based on Selected Objects from an array

Tags: powershell

Sorry for the wierd title, I didn't know how to phrase the question. I'm relatively new to Powershell and I'm writing a program. Basically, I have an array where the user has selected settings or wish to have "Selected" from the GWMI query stored in "$settings_array". I want to output the results to a CSV. When I try to run it, only the first Select statement gets output to the CSV. Output to the textbox works fine. I know it has something to do with how it's being stored in the array at each ieration. $resultList is intialized as an array ($resultList = @()). There are hundreds of lines of code for the Form and other functions, but here is the relevant code. Thanks for the help! Let me know if I need to post more of the code.

```
$colItems = GWMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $PCname -namespace "root\CimV2" -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
ForEach ($objItem in $colItems)
{ 
    ForEach ($objItem2 in $settings_array)
    {
        $resultList += $objItem  | Select $objItem2
        $richTextBox1.Appendtext("$objItem2" + ": " + $objItem.$objItem2 + "`r`n")
        $richtextbox1.ScrollToCaret()
    }
}
$resultList | export-csv "$ScriptDir\Exports\$Outputfile"
```

Comment: This worked: `$colItems | Select-Object -Property $settings_array | export-csv "$ScriptDir\Exports\$Outputfile" -NoType` after building settings array in the same function. Building $settings_array in a separate function created errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is made with rows and columns. Each object in the array you export gets a row, and each object gets a column value for each property. You add a new record/object to the resultlist with a single property every time(every object has only one property). The reason you only get the first is because your records contain different property-names. To solve this "non-static propertyname" problem, powershell takes the first object's properties as a template for the csv file. Since object2,object3 etc. doesn't include the same property, they will be blank. However, when you hit another object with the same property as the first object had, the value will be included too. Ex. you get the Name property for all network adapters, but blank values on the rest.

Your sample is missing information, ex. how `$settings_array` is built. If it's a normal string-array like:

```
$settings_array = "Name", "DisplayName", "Test"
```

or

```
$settings_array = @("Name", "DisplayName", "Test")
```

Then you can pass the whole array to `select`.

```
$colItems = GWMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $PCname  -namespace "root\CimV2" -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
ForEach ($objItem in $colItems)
{ 
    #Write to screen
    ForEach ($objItem2 in $settings_array)
    {
        $richTextBox1.Appendtext("$objItem2" + ": " + $objItem.$objItem2 + "`r`n")
        $richtextbox1.ScrollToCaret()
    }
}
#Save to CSV
$colItems | Select-Object -Property $settings_array | export-csv "$ScriptDir\Exports\$Outputfile"
```

Notice the last line. Now, the foreach loop is only used for your textbox-content, while the last line formats the CSV as it should.

**EDIT** Try this to get your settings:

```
Function GetSettings { 
    $out = @()
    Foreach ($objItem in $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems) {
        $out += $objItem.ToString()
    } 
    $out
}
$settings_array = GetSettings
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...I'll try this when I get back to work. $settings_array is built running through a loop similar to

foreach($item in $chklistbox.SelectedItems)
$settings_array += $item

I can't remember the exact syntax right now, but it is an array of strings.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I get this:
Select-Object : Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of 
the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At E:\Scripts\CSTools\CSTools.ps1:713 char:56
+                               $colItems | Select-Object <<<<  -Property $sett
ings_array | export-csv "$ScriptDir\Exports\$Outputfile"            
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupport 
   edException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co 
   mmands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: Here is the code for $settings_array 
`Function Settings(){ 
Foreach ($objItem in $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems) {$settings_array1 += [String]$objItem} Return $settings_array1 } $settings_array = Settings($this)`

Comment: This almost worked:
`$colItems | Select-Object -Property "$settings_array" | export-csv "$ScriptDir\Exports\$Outputfile" -NoType`

I get all the properties' names exported to cell A1 of the CSV, but none of the actual content from the results.

Comment: The problem seams to be Your settingsarray. I don't think Your values are converted properly. You should add codesamples in an edit to Your question, including how you create Your form(so we know that the propertynames are correct).  I've added an edit to my answer With a New "settings"-function you can try out.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simpe tip: you can export in XML with export-clixml and whatever the number of column, they are all added in the file.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, better than the output I probably would have thought of.